# AngularJS: Display the first element of the response array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I currently have a form with two dynamic dropdowns (`Location` & `Branch`). When one of `Location` values is selected, `Branch` will automatically populate the corresponding branches with that location.

```
<select ng-model="formData.location" 
        ng-options="rg as rg.type for rg in region">
    <option value="">Choose Location</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="formData.branches" 
        ng-options="c as c[formData.location.displayName] for c in formData.location.data | orderBy:'branch'">
    <option value="">Choose Branch</option>
</select>
```

The `Branch` values are taken from this controller:

```
scope.metro = [
    {"branch": "SM North EDSA", "alias": "northedsa"}, 
    {"branch": "Trinoma", "alias": "trinoma"}, 
    {"branch": "Robinsons Galleria", "alias": "robgalleria"}, 
    // etc...
];

scope.region = [
    { type: 'Metro Manila', data:scope.metro, displayName:'branch', alias:'alias'},
    { type: 'Central Luzon', data:scope.central, displayName:'branch', alias:'alias'},
    { type: 'North Luzon', data:scope.north, displayName:'branch', alias:'alias'},
    // etc...
  ];
```

Now, inside the form, on every `option` change in `Branch`, there will be a pre-generated code from the table in my database (assigned on each of its row), procured by `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="codes in response">
  <span ng-if="((codes.branch == formData.branches.alias) && (codes.taken == 0))">
  {{codes.code}}
</div>
```

My database table looks like this:

[image: database table here]

This works when it is left as it is (displaying 100 codes each iteration). But when I use a filter such as `limitTo:1`, I only get the **first index** of the row in the table of my database. What I need is to get the **first element of the `response` array** on every flip of `Branch` values.

For clearer explanation, this ng-repeat is done by having this function in my controller:

```
http.get("server/fetch.php").success(function(response){
    scope.response = response;
    // shuffleArray(scope.response);
  }).error(function() {
    scope.response = "error in fetching data";
  });
```

I was told do this in a controller instead if I wanted to get the first element of each array, but I am not sure how to do that. I will post a plunker when I have the time. I just need this solve right now as I have deadlines to meet before the day ends.

I hope this question is all clear even without a plunker. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the "offending" code, i.e. the code that doesn't do what you want

Comment: `<div ng-repeat="codes in response | limitTo:1">
  <span ng-if="((codes.branch == formData.branches.alias) && (codes.taken == 0))">
  {{codes.code}}
</div>` The AngularJS filter only gets the first index of the table in my database. It's not what I want. I need to have the first element of the response array on each `select` of `Branch`.

Comment: `| limitTo: 1` would take the first element of `response` array

Comment: you need to take the conditions you use in `ng-if` and make a custom filter for the `ng-repeat` instead. Then put that filter in and the limit:1 would be based on the filtered array instead of the whole array

Comment: @NewDev `limitTo: 1` only takes the first index, not the first element. I run it and `DZXXK768` is the only one returned even after an `option` change from `Branch`.

Comment: @charlietfl Can you suggest a way by code in doing this? I'm kind of in a dead end here. Please help. :(

Comment: @ralphcarlo, ah... you are trying to further filter the `response` by `branch`? So the `response` is the complete array and you need the first item with the selected branch, is that it?

Comment: @NewDev Yes! Yes! If I am to create a custom filter, how do I go about it? As you can see on my question, I have `fetch.php` to get the entire array from my database table.

Comment: I don't think you necessarily need a custom filter here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pipe multiple filters together, the first to filter based on branch, and next to limit the number of returned items:

```
<div ng-repeat="codes in response | filter: {branch: formData.branches.alias, taken: 0} | limitTo: 1">
   {{codes.code}}
</div>
```

In this case it was possible to use the built-in `filter` filter since it allows specifying a predicate for multiple properties to match against with an `AND` condition. For any more complex condition, I recommend using a predicate function:

```
$scope.filterBy = function(a, b){
  return function(item){
    return item.foo === a || item.bar === b;
  }
}
```

and use it like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: filterBy('foo', 'bar')">
```